# Diagnostic procedures for fallen laptop

Tags: software-rec, diagnostic, physical-damage

My laptop fell on the ground. I turned it on, nothing seems to be wrong. Going through Google search, many sites suggested looking for black spots on the screen or clicking sounds from the hard drive. None of which seems to have occurred. However, I'm still worried that the fall caused some subtle damage somehow. So, are there any software or methods I can apply to achieve deeper diagnostics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check CPU temperatures are still normal and that under load you are still getting a reasonable clock speed. While the cooler should be secure and held in place a drop can dislodge it.

I would use [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/) while running something CPU intensive and make sure that

1. CPU temperatures do not immediately spike up to 90C
2. The CPU does not drop clock speed down to 800MHz or 400MHz, which is a sign of thermal throttling.

Otherwise if it still works then it still works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, does a game count as something heavy? I run the game 
(The Sims 3 is really famous for being a heavy game). According to the criteria you just mentioned, temperature and clock rates are normal. Do you suggest something to run?

Comment: Games are usually a pretty good thing, it may not run the CPU at 100% but as they'll test both the GPU and CPU at the same time if anything that can be a slightly better load. If you have a dedicated GPU as well then it'll test both CPU and GPU heat-sinks. If it's still fine after that and the screen looks okay then only time will really tell if something else got knocked loose. If you haven't noticed anything else weird then chances are you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The best hardware test is running
[MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)
over-night, or for as long as you can.

Although primarily a memory test, it incidentally also tests the CPU and memory
controller.

If no errors are found, you can be reasonably confident that no damage was done,
but stay alert for later danger signs (such as battery drain, strange messages etc.).